# Configuring *all* JSHint settings in WebStorm IDE

Tags: jshint, webstorm

After a somewhat comprehensive evaluation of IDEs for use in front end development, WebStorm leads the pack I think.

The one missing piece is that we can't configure JSHint the way we need to. The WebStorm preferences GUI provides some options, but not the full set. The GUI only lets you configure 15 of the 30 or so actual available options.

This is a problem because we don't want to change our coding practices just because an IDE doesn't let us configure linting the way we want.

Is there a hacky way to go in and adjust the JSHint library behind the scenes for WebStorm?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can configure all the options you'd like in a `.jshintrc` file located in the root directory of your project. This will be a project-wide setting.

From https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/webhelp/jshint.html:

> Use config files
>
> Select this check box to have the code verified according to the settings from a configuration file. A configuration file is a JSON file with the extension `.jshintrc` that specifies which JSHint options should be enabled or disabled. WebStorm will look for a `.jshintrc` file in the working directory. If the search fails, WebStorm will search in the parent folder, then again in the parent folder. The process is repeated until WebStorm finds a `.jshintrc` or reaches the project root. To have WebStorm still run verification in this case, specify the default configuration file to use.

I've been using this for a while and it works great. Plus you can commit it to your repo and ensure the entire team follows the same code style. Also a great place to add globals.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work in WebStorm 11. The .jshintrc file is ignored by JsHint and it isn't updated when changing the JsHint settings in the IDE

Comment: My mistake. I thought that you would be able to edit the .jshintrc files using the IDE's JsHint configuration UI, but it seems you can't. Once you choose "Use Config File" the UI is no longer available and you have to edit the files by hand.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not aware of any hacky way to do it, but you can [vote for the existing feature request](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-85681).

Comment: There's a simple way to do it - use [`.jshintrc`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21990463/1269037)

Answer (score 2):

There's a per-file solution that works, but is not ideal. Would prefer an IDE or project-wide fix/hack.

Set JSHint options at the top of your file:

```
/*jshint laxcomma:true, asi:true */
```

Comment: This seems to not actually affect the IDE. I am sure JSHint actually does not complain; however, /*jshint expr:true*/ for instance will not prevent complaints from webstorm itself when trying to access a getter.

Comment: It's finicky about spaces, but it does work for me in the lastest, "non-stable" IDE version. Try putting a space before the last "*/"

Comment: @simpleascouldbe thank you! I couldn't get it to work until I made sure there was *no* space before jshint.   Seems like I need a linter for my linter directives!